# GatsbyJS: Display 404 page if route doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

How to correctly set up 404 page, so that if user hits any route that does not exist, it redirects to this 404 page?

Currently I have this code:

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import SEO from "../components/seo";

    const NotFoundPage = () => (
        <Layout>
            <SEO title="404: Not found" />
            <h1>NOT FOUND</h1>
            <p>You just hit a route that doesn&#39;t exist... the sadness.</p>
        </Layout>
    );
    
    export default NotFoundPage;
```

Comment: Save the file as 404.js in `pages` directory

Comment: It's already there. It works only when I write the correct route like /404, but if the user will enter any other, it does not work.

Comment: During development a custom 404 page is shown, but in your final build your 404 will be shown. Try `gatsby build`, `gatsby serve`

Answer (score 10):

If the file is called `404.js` and you place it under `src/pages/404.js` directory, it will make automatically the redirect for every non-existing page. According to [their documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.cn/docs/add-404-page/):

> To create a 404 page create a page whose path matches the regex
> `^\/?404\/?$ (/404/, /404, 404/ or 404)`. Most often you’ll want to
> create a React component page at `src/pages/404.js`.

Keep in mind that under `develop` mode your `404`, Gatsby overrides the default page and lists all your created pages and paths. However, you can still preview your `404` page by clicking "Preview custom 404 page" to verify that it’s working as expected. This is useful when you’re developing so that you can see all the available pages.

Under `build` mode everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As Ferran Buireu wrote, the good explanation is on the GatsbyJS website:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/adding-common-features/add-404-page/

But sometimes this method doesn't work when your site is running on Apache or Nginx webserver. You are getting the default Apache/Nginx 404 page instead of your beautiful GatsbyJS 404 page. That's because your webserver... (surprise!) simply doesn't find the page! And displays its own default 404 page.

How to display your own 404 page instead of default webserver 404 page? Just to add a special instruction to your virtual host config:

Apache: `ErrorDocument 404 /404/index.html` ([link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-404-page-in-apache))

Nginx: `error_page 404 /404/index.html;` ([link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04))